# Android Studio lanza excepcion "Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted" al ejecutar el proyecto en otra PC

Tags: mysql, android-studio, hosting, conexión

estuve trabajando en una aplicación en la cual utilizo un servidor remoto para las consultas a mi base de datos remota hasta aquí todo perfecto la aplicación ya esta terminada y funciona correctamente, sin embargo cuando migro el proyecto a otra PC me lanza la siguiente excepción:

> **java.io.ioexception cleartext http traffic to [("aqui va la url de mi servidor remoto")] not permitted**

Estuve investigando al respecto y se supone que debo crear un xml `network_secutiry_config` pero ya lo tengo creado y con las configuraciones necesarias, lo que no me explico es: Porque funciona correctamente en la PC donde se creo el proyecto pero al migrarlo a otra PC me lanza esa excepción? la base de datos esta en un servidor remoto, no local, lo cual no deberia darme ningún problema de conexión al momento de ejecutarlo en otras PC si en la PC de origen si funciona correctamente todo el apartado de conexiones.

**network_secutiry_config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
<domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
<domain includeSubdomains="true">https://pedidoslab.atspace.cc</domain> //Esta es la url del hosting que estoy utilizando
</domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
...
...
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_secutiry_config"
...
...
...
</application>
```

Esto es lo que tengo por ahora, existirá alguna otra configuración adicional para evitar este tipo de excepción?

De antemano muchas gracias!

Comment: pudieron solucionarlo? arranque hace unos dias con Java y android studio y no conozco bien la sintaxis, me ayudarian a implementarlo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Añade esto entre las etiquetas application de tu AndroidManifest

```
<application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"/>
```

Si persiste intenta agregándolo así

```
<application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:replace="android:usesCleartextTraffic/>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias eso funciona muy bien.

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso a demás de poner lo que comentan en la respuesta superior, tuve que modificar el network_secutiry_config.xml con...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>introducir el código aquí
```

Tal y como se comenta en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902629/how-to-allow-all-network-connection-types-http-and-https-in-android-9-pie)